# PyQt5: Opening a new window through uic.loadUi

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have something similar to the following. I want to open a new window from the top tool bar, this is `archive`, currently a new window opens but it is small and blank, it is not the one saved as archive.ui as produced by qtdesigner. The window's object name is `ArchiveWindow`.

```
class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.actionSingle_Archive.triggered.connect(self.archive)
        ...

        def archive(self):
            self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            uic.loadUi('archive.ui')
            self.window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = GUI()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [`loadUi`](https://riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/uic/uic-module.html#loadUi) documentation:

> **loadUi**(*uifile, baseinstance=None, package='', resource_suffix='_rc'*)
> Load a Qt Designer .ui file and returns an instance of the user interface.
>
> - **uifile** (*str*) – the file name or file-like object containing the `.ui` file.
> - **baseinstance** – the optional instance of the *Qt base class*. If specified then the user interface is created in it. Otherwise a new instance of the base class is automatically created.

This is what you're already doing in the `__init__`: calling `uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)` means that the UI is installed on `self` (which represents the current *instance* of `GUI`).

Just add the instance on which you want to set the UI up to the arguments.

```
    def archive(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        uic.loadUi('archive.ui', self.window)
        self.window.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You net to add the parent to uic.load, here an example:

```
uic.load('archive.ui', parent)
```

and to load the ui file as the main window, just replace parent with self:

```
uic.load('archive.ui', self)
```