# PYQT6 and QT designer, after opening second window, buttons wont work

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyqt6

So i am making a GUI to identify seagulls.
I have made some QMainWindow's and would like the user to nagviate through these using buttons.
The first window works fine, and the user gets to the next page.
However, when clicking on buttons on page 2, nothing works, not even printing a simple statement. I am new to this and i am doing something wrong. I tried messing with **init** but am at  a loss.

I am using a function

```
def openNewPage(self,b):
    
    NewPage = b.text()
    uic.loadUi(f"{NewPage}.ui",self)
    self.show
```

to open a new page by having the buttons clicked on by the user have the name of the next file to be opened.

For example: the button for white head has the text "WhiteHead"
and will the open the file WhiteHead.ui
example:

self.bWhiteHead.clicked.connect(lambda:self.openNewPage(self.bWhiteHead))

Please help me understand why buttons work in one window and not in the next, thank you.
Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6 import uic
import time

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("SeagullPage1.ui",self)
        self.setWindowTitle("SEAGULL IDENTIFIER")


        self.bBlackHead.clicked.connect(lambda:self.openNewPage(self.bBlackHead))
        self.bWhiteHead.clicked.connect(lambda:self.openNewPage(self.bWhiteHead))  

    def openNewPage(self,b):
        
        NewPage = b.text()
        uic.loadUi(f"{NewPage}.ui",self)
        self.show
    
    
class WhiteHead(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__

        self.setWindowTitle("SEAGULL IDENTIFIER2") 
            
        self.BlackFeetButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.openNewPage(self.BlackFeetButton))
        self.PinkFeetButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.openNewPage(self.PinkFeetButton))
        self.YellowFeetButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.openNewPage(self.YellowFeetButton))   
    

    def openNewPage(self,b):
        print("hey")
        NewPage = b.text()
        uic.loadUi(f"{NewPage}.ui",self)
        self.show
        

class YellowFeet(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("SEAGULL IDENTIFIER3")

        self.RedBeakButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.openNewPage(self.RedBeakButton))
        self.NonReadBeakButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.openNewPage(self.NonReadBeakButton))

    def openNewPage(self,b):
        print("hey")
        NewPage = b.text()
        uic.loadUi(f"{NewPage}.ui",self)
        self.show
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()

    app.exec()

#sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243030/pyqt5-opening-a-new-window-through-uic-loadui

Comment: Thank you!! Ill have a look when i Get home.

Comment: If you want to navigate through windows (in this case, a more correct term would be "pages"), do ***not*** do that, because you're not just updating the UI, but also completely destroying any previous object (which you may need), also the signals are only connected in the `__init__` (which is why it doesn't work). Don't do it like this, use QStackedWidget along with QWidgets instead of QMainWindow, so that you can also easily navigate forward or backward (or even jump between pages). Besides, using the text of a button as static reference for a file name is a *terrible* idea.